# Callable statement not returning response in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Code:

```
       callableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall("{CALL_Sample_Procedure(?)");
       stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);// in Constant
        stmt.setString(1, result);
        logger.getLogger("executing");
        stmt.execute();
        result = stmt.getString(1);
```

The above procedure works and returns the response for small volume of data e.g. 20k records insertion.

However, for over 100k records the `stmt.execute` doesn't return any response and it keeps printing in log "executing" but in database all the records are processed.

The code should fetch the result value after execution, which is required to execute another procedure.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: your question seems vague and there is some incomplete description of your problem. what is the output of your storedprocedure? are you trying to fetch some data from your registered output or there is a select statement for example in your sp and then you are trying to fetch more resulted records from that select statement?

Comment: Output for Stored Procedure is string value  "Success/ Failure".Registered Parameter just fetches variable value after sp execution is completed.Stored procedure has multiple insert, update statements based on conditions.@epcpu

Comment: It's a String value "Success/Failure" @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: It appears to me, from what you posted, that `CALL_Sample_Procedure` is a PL/SQL procedure that takes one IN-OUT parameter of type `varchar`. My guess is that the issue you are experiencing is due to the PL/SQL procedure code. Perhaps you could post that code?